# Positive powers of k in long data type

Tags: java

I have to print all the positive powers of integer k in the java **long** data type.
My code is:

```
int k = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int i = 1;
    long a = k;
    while (a <= Long.MAX_VALUE) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
        System.out.println(a);
        i++;
        a = (long) Math.pow(k, i);
      }
```

an infinite loop is created when i run this program.

But,when I run this program with a small change :(I have just removed the equals to operator in **while** condition)

```
int k = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int i = 1;
    long a = k;
    while (a < Long.MAX_VALUE) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
        System.out.println(a);
        i++;
        a = (long) Math.pow(k, i);
       }
```

It works fine as far as i think after that small change.
But,I am not able to understand what is happening here.

Comment: Well if a is equal to the max, in your next iteration it would go over, so wouldn't you get an error when you try casting it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is the cast from `double` to `long` following the `Math.pow()` call. `double`s can hold much larger numbers than `long`s, and if you try to cast a large `double` to `long`, you'll get `Long.MAX_VALUE`. Your first loop will never exit, because all exponents after a certain point will just return `Long.MAX_VALUE`.

See for yourself:

```
public class DoubleToLong {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println((long)Double.MAX_VALUE);
        System.out.println(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    }
}
```

Returns:

```
9223372036854775807
9223372036854775807
```

Answer (score 1):

The long data type is a 64-bit two's complement integer. if you check your results in both the cases, you will find at after certain number of iterations it reaches its max value, and subsequent iterations will restrict your calculation result to long's max value only. Hence <= condition will never be false because it will remain equal to long max.
When you remove equals condition, it will break after closest value it could reach towards long max.

Try with K as 2, that certain number of iteration is 63. (As long is 64 bit)

Comment: Yes, you are right.The value of A remains the same as the max value after further iterations.

Answer (score 0):

A silently overflows. Calculate the number of iterations up front instead and loop that number of times instead.